# App rejection possibility in appstore

Tags: ios

Recently I uploaded an app to the appstore but it got rejected because the app has links to the website where one can purchase(as per apple rejection statement). In the app there is no purchase section. Any user can use the app but has to register via website or through the app. The app has three sections, where two sections can be used by any user but inorder to use the third section one has to purchase a package through the website. The user cannot use the app to purchase but has to use the browser and go directly to the website and make the purchase. Now I am planning to resubmit the app by removing the links to the website, other functionalities will remain the same. My question is, whether there is any chance for rejection of my app because of this type of purchasing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the purchasing is allowed. But no links to a website, where a digital product / account / subscription etc. may be bought is allowed. If no link appears anymore, you will pass the approval.

Answer (score 0):

Any links from within your application that go to a website where there are other links where the user can purchase something will be rejected.

I have had an app rejected because they were able to drill down into the links about 5 links deep then got to a page where a user could purchase something on my site. Your best bet is to create a stand alone registration page where there is no links to any other pages within your application.

Apple wants to make money off any purchases and by allowing the user to navigate outside the AppStore purchasing where they do not make a profit, they will deny your application.